# Honda CRV 2000 Model Unusual sound when accelerating

Tags: honda, noise

My Honda CRV 2000 model has for some months now making big huuuuuuuu big unusual sound when you start accelerating beyond 20km/h. Before it only use to change the sound at 60kn/h now it has come down to 20km/h. Of late, even the vibration in front is accompanying. What can cause this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are there any codes present?

Answer (score 2):

The problem of the sound is now gone. It was purely the issue of a wheel bearing though at first the mechanic did not tell which tyre had a faulty bearing. He had to suspend the front tyres and then he started the vehicle, put it in drive and released the hand brake. As the wheels were spinning, it was clear as to which tyre had an issue just by listening to the tyres one by one. Bye PULE G, Zambia.